# I have 100+ if statements. Can/Should I be using a foreach or something else?

Tags: php

I have a form that asks users questions and for each question there is one checkbox that can be selected.

e.g.

1. Do you want to know about apples?'

   - Checkbox: 'Yes'
2. Do you want to know about purple?

   - Checkbox: 'Yes'
3. Do you want to know about George Washington?

   - Checkbox: 'Yes'

Once the form is submitted, there will be a paragraph of text output for each checked box.

e.g.
If the user checks the question about 'apples' and the question about 'George Washington' then after they submit the form they will see:

- Here is a paragraph of text about apples.
- Here is a paragraph of text about George Washington.

If have code that gets my desired output, but it involves having an if statement for every question - and there are about 100 questions - so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient/sophisticated method.

The question field metanames and values are like this:

- my_prefix_apples (value: Apples)
- my_prefix_purple (value: Purple)
- my_prefix_george_washington (value: George Washington)

Here is my code just using the three aforementioned questions as an example:

```php
// Declare the question metas
$questionMetas = [
    'apples',
    'purple',
    'george_washington',
];

// Save the paragraphs of text that will be output
$applesText = "Here is a paragraph of text about apples.";
$purpleText = "Here is a paragraph of text about purple.";
$georgeText = "Here is a paragraph of text about George Washington.";

// Use table tag to open the table before looping
echo "<table>";

// Loop over all question metas
foreach ($questionMetas as $questionMeta){
    // Save the question values
    $questions = $fields['my_prefix_' . $questionMeta]['value'];

    // If the current field is empty skip to the next field
    if (empty($questions)){
        continue;
    }

    // For the questions that the user selected,
    // output the paragraphs in a table
    if ($questions === Apples){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>$applesText</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($questions === Purple){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>$purpleText</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($questions === 'George Washington'){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>$georgeText</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

// Close table
echo "</table>";
```

I've been trying to replace the 100+ if statements with another foreach ($questions as $question) and a switch but I can't find the right way to do it. It either breaks or doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be much better off with using associative arrays, so the key is the question and the value is the text..

```
$questionMetas = [
    'apples' => "Here is a paragraph of text about apples.",
    'purple' => "Here is a paragraph of text about purple.",
    'george_washington' => "Here is a paragraph of text about George Washington."
];
```

Then the output just means putting the relevant text out using `$questions` as the key...

```
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>-</td>";
        echo "<td>{$questionMetas[$questions]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been trying to do this but couldn't get the syntax right. Even with your answer I still had to fiddle a bit (I did: foreach ($questionMetas as $questionMetas => $text) and then echo $text). But this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write another foreach loop, It can be handled in same loop

```
 <?php
       // Declare the question metas
    $questionMetas = [
        'apples',
        'purple',
        'george_washington',
    ];

    // Save the paragraphs in the array
    $questionMetasText = [
        'Here is a paragraph of text about apples.',
        'Here is a paragraph of text about purple.',
        'Here is a paragraph of text about George Washington',
    ];

    $counterForTextPosition = 0;
    // Use table tag to open the table before looping
    echo "<table>";

    // Loop over all question metas
    foreach ($questionMetas as $questionMeta){
        // Save the question values
        if(isset($fields['my_prefix_' . $questionMeta]['value'])){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>-</td>";
                echo "<td>$questionMetasText[$counterForTextPosition] </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        $counterForTextPosition++;
        // If the current field is empty skip to the next field
        if (empty($questions)){
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Close table
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Further you can use the associative array to eliminate 2 arrays and just hold single one

Comment: Thank you! This produced my desired output and set me off toward reading up on isset and counters - neither of which I'd used before.